Framework for cross-platform mobile app with notifications?
Background
I want to create a cross-platform mobile app with notifications and am looking at different options. I'm going to be the only developer, and i've developed on Android previously and am learning JavaScript at the moment. (Here are some notes about the project as a whole: link)
Requirements

Cross-platform - mainly iOS+Android (bonus: web)

Some way of deploying to iOS without having to pay 99 US dollars each year


Free/libre and gratis
Notifications (to be sent in the morning and evening)
Local storage

I'm developing on Ubuntu and have access to a Windows computer and Android Phone. MacOS and iOS is harder for me to get though. So cross-compiling (or similar) is a bonus, but not a requirement
What i've found so far
I've been looking into PWAs during the last week, but from what i can understand it seems they cannot reliably send background notifications when running through Safari on iOS (see table here).
Question
What framework would you recommend that i use?
